# How to itterate the array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

device is not displayed on the screen when the owner is at index 1 or more than one. but if the owner is at index 0 the device is displayed on the screen thanks for the help in advance

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('devices')
          .where('owner', isEqualTo: [user.uid]).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot data) {
                Device device = Device.fromData(data.data, data.documentID);
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(device.name),
                    subtitle: Text(device.deviceStatus),
                    leading: Icon(device.deviceIcon),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (data['type'] == 'light') {
                        _selectDevice(context, device);
                      }
                    },
                    onLongPress: () {
                      _selectDeviceadmin(context, device);
                    });
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

[image: FireStore]

Answer (score 0):

You might extract the code creating the ListView to the method (_buildListOfDevices in my example below) which creates the list of ListTile widgets. Depending whether the first owner ID is equal to the user ID the ListTile is added to the widgets list or not. So the code could look like:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('devices')
      .where('owner', isEqualTo: [user.uid]).snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      default:
        return _buildListOfDevices(context, snapshot.data.documents);
    },
  );
}

Widget _buildListOfDevices(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  List<Widget> devices = List();
  for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshot) {
    Device device = Device.fromData(documentSnapshot.data, documentSnapshot.documentID);
    if (device.owner.first == user.uid) {
      devices.add(ListTile(
          title: Text(device.name),
          subtitle: Text(device.deviceStatus),
          leading: Icon(device.deviceIcon),
          onTap: () {
            if (documentSnapshot['type'] == 'light') {
              _selectDevice(context, device);
            }
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            _selectDeviceadmin(context, device);
          }));
    }
  }

  return ListView(
    children: devices,
  );
}
```